# jQuery .removeClass() not working properly

Tags: jquery, css

I am doing some custom form validation and highlighting areas that the user still needs to fill in. I add a class onto a fieldset using the .addClass method which changes the border box around the fieldset to red. When the user clicks the submit button I run a function that first clears the validation css classes and rechecks the form to see if the user has the proper input. The border box is not changing back to the original color when removeClass() is called. It stays red.

```
//Add
$('#jdeABFieldSet').addClass("validatorBox");
//Remove
$(".validatorBox").removeClass("validatorBox");
```

I have also tried

```
$("#jdeABFieldSet").removeAttr('class');
$("#jdeABFieldSet").attr("class", "");
```

CSS

```
.validatorBox{
    border-color: red;
}
```

Full Code below.

```
//This is where the class is added to change the border color to red.
switch($('#tbJDEName').val().length === 0 ||
                $('#tbMailingAddress').val().length === 0 ||
                $('#tbCity').val().length === 0 ||
                $('#tbState').val().length === 0 ||
                $('#tbZip').val().length === 0 ||
                $('#tbCounty').val().length === 0 ||
                $('#ddlLocationCode').val() === "default" ||
                $('#ddlSearchType').val() === "default") {
                    case $('#tbJDEName').val().length === 0:
                        $('#jdeABFieldSet').addClass("validatorBox");
                        $('#tbJDEName').addClass("validatorBox");
                        alert("JDE Address Book Request section must be filled out.");
                        break;
                    case $('#tbMailingAddress').val().length === 0:
                        $('#jdeABFieldSet legend').addClass("validatorText");
                        $('#jdeABFieldSet').addClass("validatorBox");
                        $("label[for='tbMailingAddress']").addClass("validatorText");
                        //$('#tbMailingAddress').addClass("validatorText");
                        alert("JDE Address Book Request section must be filled out.");
                        break;
                    case $('#tbCity').val().length === 0:
                        $('#jdeABFieldSet').addClass("validatorBox");
                        $('#tbCity').addClass("validatorText");
                        alert("JDE Address Book Request section must be filled out.");
                        break;
                    case $('#tbState').val().length === 0:
                        $('#jdeABFieldSet').addClass("validatorBox");
                        $('#tbState').addClass("validatorText");
                        alert("JDE Address Book Request section must be filled out.");
                        break;
                    case $('#tbZip').val().length === 0:
                        $('#jdeABFieldSet').addClass("validatorBox");
                        $('#tbZip').addClass("validatorText");
                        alert("JDE Address Book Request section must be filled out.");
                        break;
                    case $('#tbCounty').val().length === 0:
                        $('#jdeABFieldSet').addClass("validatorBox");
                        $('#tbCounty').addClass("validatorText");
                        alert("JDE Address Book Request section must be filled out.");
                        break;
                    case $('#ddlLocationCode').val().length === 0:
                        $('#jdeABFieldSet').addClass("validatorBox");
                        $('#ddlLocationCode').addClass("validatorText");
                        alert("JDE Address Book Request section must be filled out.");
                        break;
                    case $('#ddlSearchType').val().length === 0:
                        $('#jdeABFieldSet').addClass("validatorBox");
                        $('#ddlSearchType').addClass("validatorText");
                        alert("JDE Address Book Request section must be filled out.");
                        break;
                }

//This function is the first thing called when the user clicks submit to clear the classes
function clearValidationClass() {
            $(".validatorBox").removeClass("validatorBox");
            $(".validatorText").removeClass("validatorText");
        }
```

Comment: In isolation there's no reason those lines of code wouldn't work. We need to see more of your code to understand what is (or is not) happening

Comment: In what way is this function not working properly? Please provide additional details in your question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see edits

Comment: @Serlite see edits

Comment: two quick things to check: 1/ are you sure your `clearValidationClass` is called ? 2/ when you check the DOM from the console, are the `.validatorBox` and `.validatorText` still present on the fields ?

Comment: @user2756091 `var` is your friend.

Comment: @ValLeNain the clearValidationClass() function is being called. The .validatorText class is removed in that function and is working properly just not the border-box color that is associated with the .validatorBox class

Comment: @user275691 from the console, if you click a DOM element, you can see the CSS rules applied to it and so you should be able to see why the border is still red (adn where the rule comes from) -  EDIT I might have misunderstood: you say the `.validatorText` is removed, not the `.validatorBox` ? Just one out of two ?

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that you can't remove a class from the class itself.
Try to do something like this:

```
$("#jdeABFieldSet").removeClass("validatorBox");
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This is incorrect. You should test it next time. Take a [look](https://jsfiddle.net/9g50n0ja/)